# use git's prepare-commit-msg hook during an interactive rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, commitizen

In a lerna/yarn monorepo, we use `commitizen` and `cz-conventional-changelog` to manage releases. We use `husky` to lint commit messages in the `commit-msg` hook and run the commitizen cli in the `prepare-commit-msg` hook:

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "prepare-commit-msg": "exec < /dev/tty && yarn commit --hook || true"
    }
  },
```

This works fine as long as a rebase is not required, however, while our team are still learning the ropes, we often need to rebase feature branches in order to fix commit messages.

```
git rebase --interactive origin/master
```

While running the rebase, if I choose the `reword` command, I will be able to edit the commit message in my editor, but the commitizen cli will not run, in other words, there's nothing to prevent us from committing bad commit messages.

While we do lint commit messages in CI, I would much rather avoid this problem altogether by enforcing use of the commitizen CLI wizard at all stages.

### Question:

Can I configure git to use the `prepare-commit-msg` hook during rebase `reword` operations?

Answer (score 2):

`git rebase` runs `pre-rebase` and `post-rewrite` hooks. I doubt it runs any other hooks.

I think you can use [`git rebase --exec`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--xltcmdgt) to run a validation script after every rebased commit. Any error code pauses rebase process.